# Хинт опции расширенного поиска имеет странный перенос строк

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн, поиск

При отображении всплывающей подсказки опций [расширенного поиска](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search) наблюдается странный перенос строк (см. Советы по использованию расширенного поиска):

[image: ответы]

[image: вопросы]

[image: закрытые]

[image: дубликаты]

[image: перенесенные]

[image: общие]

Аналогичная ситуация наблюдается и на других сайтах сети Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should now be fixed, thanks.

Должно быть уже исправлено. Спасибо за сообщение.